# jQuery validate - regra skip_or_fill_minimum não dispara se utilizada mais de uma vez

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Eu tenho um formulário que é composto por quatro `inputs` e eles estão agrupados em pares.

A regra para este formulário é muito simples, se eu preencher um dos inputs do par, eu tenho que preencher o outro também ou não preencher nenhum. Para atingir este comportamento eu usei o método `skip_or_fill_minimun`.

**O HTML:**

```
<div id="msgErros"></div>
<form>
    <label for="dataInicial">Data Inicial</label>
    <input type="text" name="filtro.dataInicial" id="dataInicial" class="datas" />
    <label for="dataFinal">Data Final</label>
    <input type="text" name="filtro.dataFinal" id="dataFinal" class="datas" />
    <br />
    <label for="tempoInicial">Tempo Inicial</label>
    <input type="text" name="filtro.tempoInicial" id="tempoInicial" class="tempos" />
    <label for="tempoFinal">Tempo Final</label>
    <input type="text" name="filtro.tempoFinal" id="tempoFinal" class="tempos" />
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**As regras de validação, mensagens e grupos:**

```
$("form").validate({
    rules : {
        "filtro.dataInicial": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".datas"]
        },
        "filtro.dataFinal": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".datas"]
        },
        "filtro.tempoInicial": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".tempos"]
        },
        "filtro.tempoFinal": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".tempos"]
        }
    },
    messages: {
        "filtro.dataInicial": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: "Por favor, preencha ambos os campos de data ou nenhum deles."
        },
        "filtro.dataFinal": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: "Por favor, preencha ambos os campos de data ou nenhum deles."
        },
        "filtro.tempoInicial": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: "Por favor, preencha ambos os campos de tempo ou nenhum deles."
        },
        "filtro.tempoFinal": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: "Por favor, preencha ambos os campos de tempo ou nenhum deles."
        }
    },
    groups : {
        grupoDatasAtendimentoSintetico : "filtro.dataInicial filtro.dataFinal",
        grupoTemposAtendimentoSintetico : "filtro.tempoInicial filtro.tempoFinal"
    },
    errorContainer : "#msgErros ul",
    errorLabelContainer : "#msgErros",
    wrapper : "li"
});
```

O problema acontecendo é que se eu preencher um dos dois primeiros inputs a regra não é acionada, o problema não ocorre se eu faço isso com o segundo par. Se eu excluir o segundo par a regra executa perfeitamente, então eu acho que é um bug. Aqui está um [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgioseffi/82g5A/).

Eu li sobre este método e `require_from_group` causando problemas que simplesmente impedem que outros métodos de serem executados, mas este bug supostamente foi corrigido na versão 1.11.1 , que é o que eu estou usando no meu projeto e no [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgioseffi/82g5A/) tanto para o próprio plugin e os métodos adicionais dele.

O problema só acontece quando o usuário preenche um dos campos no primeiro par. Alguém sabe se este é mais um bug? Eu não encontrei nada relacionado a isso no [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues) deste plugin.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO:**

Crie um entrada no issue tracker do plugin no endereço: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/1008.

Comment: Você está tendo esse problema em algum browser específico? Testei seu fiddle no Chrome e no Firefox e não consegui reproduzir o problema.

Comment: Utilizo os últimos Chrome, FF e IE. E como você fez o teste? Preencha somente o primeiro campo ou o segundo e envie o formulário.

Comment: Ok, entendi. A mensagem avisando do problema aparece, **mas mesmo assim** ele deixa submeter o formulário.

Comment: Exatamente isso, ele avisa, mas submete e não deveria submeter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema que você apresenta foi resolvido [num commit recente](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/commit/e5207d63a831fdfa30ea6927906288ae60336c76#diff-82185dc776c598c0eaf19f2c0f743011).

Veja [o seu Fiddle atualizado](http://jsfiddle.net/82g5A/2/). Eu removi as dependências externas, copiei e colei o código de http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js no início do JavaScript, em seguida colei o código de http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js - e por fim mantive o seu JavaScript inalterado.

Depois, peguei o código mais recente do "skip_or_fill_minimum" aqui: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/additional/skip_or_fill_minimum.js

E, finalmente, colei esse código substituindo a versão anterior que estava no Fiddle.

Com isso, o erro sumiu! De onde se conclui que o bug de fato existia mas já foi corrigido.

Comment: O que havia de errado no meu código? O que eu tenho que fazer para o formulário ser validado do jeito que eu preciso?

Comment: @JBruni pelo que entendi a correção do método que você colou na minha pergunta no SO em Inglês não é a que está na versão 1.11.1, correto?

Comment: A versão 1.11.1 é de 22 de março de 2013 (https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/tree/1.11.1). O commit que corrige o erro é de 27 de agosto de 2013 (https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/commit/e5207d63a831fdfa30ea6927906288ae60336c76)

Comment: Não tem nada de errado com o seu código. É um bug. O bug está presente na versão 1.11.1 - ou você espera uma nova versão, ou você aplica a correção por conta própria.

Comment: Para aplicar a correção por conta própria, tem que substituir o trecho indicado na resposta (código mais recente do "skip_or_fill_minimum"). Use a versão não-minimizada do "additional-methods.js" (e depois minimize você mesmo com "uglify.js", se quiser).

Comment: @JBruni, obrigado por ajudar.

Comment: Em tempo, devo copiar o require_from_group também?

Comment: Acho que é uma boa ideia sim. (No caso, não é **necessário**, porque você está usando somente o "skip_or_fill_minimum", portanto não faz diferença. Porém, sabemos que o "require_from_group" também foi corrigido, por isso é uma boa ideia.)

Comment: Eu uso em outro form sim, e como o problema é o mesmo pros dois métodos vou atualizar os dois.